# Maximum base for parseInt()?

Tags: javascript, parsing

The second parameter of `parseInt()` defines the base to which the first parameter is parsed to. I have been playing around with some numbers and found out that I do not get a correct answer anymore if the base is larger than 36:

```
parseInt("1", 36);
// -> 1

parseInt("1", 37);
// -> NaN
```

**Is there a limit? And why is it 36?**

*I was using chrome when I ran my tests*

Comment: You answered your question, it is 36. And it is a radix, not base.

Comment: @epascarello There is also the question "And why is it 36?"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

36 is 10 + 26. There are 26 letters in the alphabet, plus 0-9. 
That's the maximum radix you can use.

Answer (score 11):

[The ECMAScript specification specifies the maximum radix as 36.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2)

- There are 10 digits: (0-9)
- There are 26 characters: (a-z)

```
10 + 26 = 36
```

---

It should also be mentioned that it would be possible to support a radix higher than `36`. The spec could be adjusted to use case-sensitive characters for a radix >36, say 37-62. Special characters, such as with symbols and accented letters *could* be used.

The reason that they're not, is that it's ambiguous, and unnecessary. Parsing algorithms for custom radixes shouldn't be too difficult, and could be written on an as-needed basis.

Limiting the radix to 36 helps balance performance with utility.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum is 36, because that's the amount of digits and chars the standard alphabet has (0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz). If you wonder about anything else like this, you might want to [bookmark the official ECMAScript language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/), it's all there